# /etc/init.d sh script

Tags: python, linux

I'm new to python. I want to create controlled script executed from /etc/init.d command like /etc/init.d something start/stop/restart

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: These scripts should be programmed in shell, not in Python. http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/tocsysinit.html

Comment: Why?  I believe you, but I'd like to know what the rationale is, and especially what trouble I can get into.

Comment: For completeness I asked the question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/200424/init-d-scripts-written-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a module for constructing daemons.  I've used this: https://gist.github.com/slor/5946334

Comment: Nice full example given here.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 3):

See [this post](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28) on how to write a script to place in your /etc/init.d directory. The only difference is you must change the hash-bang line to point to python, and not bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def myfunc():
    print 'myfunct()'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'running python script'
    myfunc()
```

And make the file executable

```
chmod +x myscript
```

Answer (score 1):

Pardus initialization (http://www.pardus.org.tr/eng/projects/comar/SpeedingUpLinuxWithPardus.html) is based on python and in theory you can even start system with windows executable (through Wine of course). You can see a sample initialisation script there doing almost same thing with shell script but in a pythonic way.